# completionTimeOut or timeout with TimeoutAwareAggregationStrategy

Tags: java, apache-camel

I'm using multicast to send the incoming message to two different endpoints and aggregating the response.I would like to get the response,even if one of the endpoint response timed out.
which method i can use "timeout" or  completionTimeout.?
I'm using parallel processing for processing message.

```
 .multicast()
 .to("direct:A","direct:B")
 .parallelProcessing()
 //.timeout(1000L)
 .aggregationStrategy(new MyAggregationStrategy())
 //.completionTimeout(2000L)
 .end()
```

How can i use TimeoutAwareAggregationStrategy in this case.

```
public class MyAggregationStrategy implements TimeoutAwareAggregationStrategy {
@Override
public Exchange aggregate(Exchange newExchange, Exchange originalExchange) {
    if(newExchange==null){
        return originalExchange;
    }
    else {
        ExchangeHelper.copyResults(originalExchange, newExchange);
        return originalExchange;
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `timeout`, and see this unit test for an example: https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/camel-core/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/processor/MulticastParallelTimeoutAwareTest.java